# Reading Time based data that has an offset

Tags: pandas

I have 10 Hz data that has some values offset by 1 80 Hz frame.  This means not all rows have the same number of terms.  I'm trying to read this into a dataframe using read_table.   Pandas complains that the rows aren't even.  A sample of the data looks like this:

```
SGMT    Foo Bar Baz Qux
2010/056/12:25:32.100   2.16123839150863E-03    1.95636410755160E+00
2010/056/12:25:32.112                   -9.9458          6.063645E+2
2010/056/12:25:32.200   2.16123839150863E-03    1.95636410755160E+00
2012/056/12:25:32.212                   -9.9452          6.059189E+2
2010/056/12:25:32.300   2.16123839150863E-03    1.95636410755160E+00
```

In reality, there are 36 columns of data on the even 10 hz marks and 6 on the offset ones.

My attempt at reading the code looks like this:

```
env_values = pd.read_table(filen, sep ='[\t ]*',index_col='SGMT', \
                parse_dates='SGMT', date_parser=time_convert)
```

and the function time_covert is

```
def time_convert(tstr):
    return pd.to_datetime(tstr, format='%Y/%j/%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I want all the data to appear as if it happened on the 10 Hz boundry (0.100, 0.200) mark, and be one row in the pandas dataframe.

Can read_table do this or do I have to write a preprocessor to time align the data before giving it to pd.read_table?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by time align the data? For example, what would the row at time `2010/056/12:25:32.112` look like in your final df? Would it be at 12:25:32.1 or 12:25:32.2? Would it contain 6 or 36 columns?

Comment: I would like the df to only show times for 12:25:32.1, .2 etc but have all measurements in it.  Pretend all data came from the 10 Hz mark and none were offset.   So, can pd.read_table do that?  Or do I have to write a python script to move data from the 12:25:32.112 to 12:25:32.100 before I give it to read_table?

Comment: Okay, so then you will have two rows for the same timestamp? One which has 36 columns and one which has only 6 columns?